# How i can know when AsynsTask is ready from Activity

Tags: android, android-asynctask, thread-sleep

How i can know when AsynsTask is ready from Activity? I can not write my code in a separate class, because i use ListView, and fill him. How i can do that without Thread.sleep ?

Comment: use a delegate (aka listener)

Comment: basically asynctask can have Pre-Execute / doInBackground and Post-Execute. Pre-Execute = before doing the actions, doInBackground = filling your listview, postExecute = displaying the items fetched.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the **onPreExecute and onPostExecute methods** of AysncTask to update your UI i.e Activity. Because this methods directly run on main thread

Comment: This is the answer. These methods were incorporated strictly to allow interaction between your background async thread and your main ui